# Предложения товаров ограничен(н)ы

Tags: орфография

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я это в метро увидел, и я понял, что что-то не так. Как правильно?

> Предложения товаров ограничены.

> Предложения товаров ограниченны.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильный вариант: *Предложения товаров **ограниченны**.*

Русский орфографический словарь: **ограниченный**; кр. ф. прич. -ен, -ена; кр. ф. прил. -ен, -ена (с дополн.: её интересы ограничены домом и детьми) и ****-ен, -енна (без дополн.:**** наши **возможности ограниченны;** она самоуверенна и ограниченна)

В данном случае (на рекламе) **не время**  ограничивает  предложение (это указание на короткое время **доставки**).

**Дополнения нет,** поэтому  это краткое **прилагательное** (товара в магазине  не слишком много, наши возможности ограниченны).

Comment: Реклама некорректна. Так?

Comment: Почему некорректна? Там же страус нарисован.  Обещают БЫСТРО доставить товар, если вы вовремя его закажете.  А то его может не хватить.

Comment: Вы сами сказали, что с двумя.

Comment: Я не вижу, что написано на плакате. Надо было обозначить. Правильно НН. Если у них Н. то это ошибка. Но у них написано: есть ограничения. Значит, товар ограниченный. Но мы выбираем Н/НН в конкретном предложении с КРАТКИМ прилагательным, где нет ДОПОЛНЕНИЯ, А если дополнение в таком предложении будет указано, то надо писать Н.  Такое правило!

Comment: Примечание. Такие задачи решать без словаря практически невозможно.

Answer (score -1):

Верно:

***Предложения товаров ограничены (= были ограничены кем-то)***.

*Ограниченный* — причастие, образованное от глагола сов. вида *ограничить*.

*Ограничен -ны -на -но* — краткое причастие, а краткие причастия всегда пишутся с одной Н.

В этом случае сказуемое имеет глагольное значение.

***Предложения товаров ограниченны***. В этом случае сказуемое обозначает признак главного слова и не имеет глагольного значения.

**[Пункт 7 — 8.](http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=62)**

Comment: Работайте по словарю РАН!  Орфографический словарь - это то, по чему надо сверять все правила.  Его корректируют постоянно, на него и надо ориентироваться.  Сколько уж раз обсуждалась эта тема!

Comment: Sharon, даже из школы известно, что краткие причастия пишутся с одной Н. Розенталь хуже, что ли? Слово _ограничены_ образовано от глагола, поэтому причастие. Есть приставка — тем более причастие, поэтому в ПОЛНОЙ форме ДВЕ Н. Но в краткой причастий, а это причастие, а не придагательное, если образовано от глагола,  всегда будет одна.

Comment: Про школу забудьте! Только по словарю РАН! Учитесь читать то, чо там написано.  Есть краткие прилагательные с особыми свойствами. Не знаете тему!

Comment: Sharon, как знаете. Но больше мне добавить здесь нечего.

Comment: Считайте как хотите. Розенталь не хуже.

Comment: Ответ неверен!!

Comment: Спорить больше сил нет. Поэтому просто останусь при своем мнении. Точка.

Comment: За свои мнения, отличные от правил, будете получать минусы. А в правилах вы тоже еще не разобрались, можно и правило подобрать. Ведете себя как-то странно.  Что значит ТОЧКА?

Comment: @Sharon https://gufo.me/search?term=Ограниченный держите. Вот что там написано: _О/грани́ч/енн/ый; __кр. ф. прич__. о/грани́ч/ен/, ог/рани́ч/еН/а; __кр. ф. прил.__ о/грани́ч/ен/, о/грани́ч/еНН/а_. То есть если это прилагательное, то в краткой форме две Н, но если краткое причастие — одна Н.

Comment: Эта тема решается только по словарю РАН  https://gramota.ru/poisk?query=ограниченный&mode=all  ДОПОЛНЕНИЯ нет.  И ведь обо всем сказано в моем ответе и в комментариях!

Comment: Максим, а дальше по своей ссылке не видите? ограниченный; кр. ф. прич. -ен, -ена; **кр. ф. прил. -ен, -ена** (с дополн.: её интересы ограниче**н**ы домом и детьми) и -ен, -е**нн**а (без дополн.: наши возможности ограниче**нн**ы; она самоуверенна и ограниче**нн**а) Орфографический словарь Лопатина.

Comment: @Sharon Уговорили. Удалю ответ. И на всякий задам вопрос Грамоте (это уже для себя — для того, чтобы на 100 % точно удостовериться, — а не для продолжения спора!). Как только прочитаете, удалю.

Comment: А то оставьте, для наглядности.  Будем сверять Грамоту с форумом. И я вас не уговариваю, а делаю замечание.

Comment: @Sharon Зачем оставлять неверный ответ?

Comment: Как хотите. Вы же еще сомневаетесь и проверить желаете.  Проверьте, а потом удалите.

Comment: @Sharon Как скажете.

Comment: Это всего лишь пожелание)